# Is there any option to lower divs id by one with loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of divs with these ids: `en_1`, `en_2`, `en_3`, `en_4`. I build a div remove button and the expected result its that when I remove `en_2`, all others divs that their number id, (like `_2`, `_4` etc) bigger than removed will change to lower by one.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 for (var is = 1; is <= 4; is++) {
  $('#delete_' + is).on('click', {is}, function(e) {
    var deleted = e.data.is;
    $('#en_' + deleted).remove();
    for(var set = (deleted + 1); set <= 4; set++) {
   $('#en_' + set).attr({id: 'en_'+(set-1)});
    }
  }
 }
});
```

I expect to remove div id= `en_2` and change `en_3` to `en_2` and also set `en_4` to `en_3`

but the current state its that all divs I expected to be lower in one - removed.

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to need to do this I wouldn't bother. Use a class instead with data attributes.

Comment: you are using 4 buttons with different id's too right?

Comment: @Kashan you right. the buttons create with for loop.

Comment: Just write this loop (if that's working) inside a function, and call that function again after every delete action (after the div 2 has been removed).

Comment: If you explain your use-case we might be able to suggest other ways of writing your HTML where you don't have to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I found with your code was that the function to remove and switch the IDs is in the for loop.

The solution is to move the function outside the for loop

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function removeElement(index) {
    return function(e) {
      var deleted = e.data.is;
      $('#en_' + deleted).remove();
      for(var set = (deleted + 1); set <= 4; set++) {
        $('#en_' + set).attr({id: 'en_'+(set-1)});
      }
    }
  }
  for (var is = 1; is <= 4; is++) {
    $('#delete_' + is).on('click', {is}, removeElement(is));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="en_1">a</div>
<div id="en_2">b</div>
<div id="en_3">c</div>
<div id="en_4">d</div>

<button id="delete_1">1</button>
<button id="delete_2">2</button>
<button id="delete_3">3</button>
<button id="delete_4">4</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand my problem. I has need to call to function outside the loop.

Comment: I had a question. my divs create dynamically. so I found a bug. When I remove some div, and after that add dynamic div - its remove all other divs that need to change their `id`. you have an idea?

Comment: I don't understand your question, maybe you could post a new question with a piece of code ?

Comment: I create the `en_number` divs by click on btn with jquery.

Comment: I think you should create a new stackoverflow question with your code so that someone can help ;) It's really hard without the code

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery

https://jsfiddle.net/r1t063ha/1/

```
<div id="en_1" class="counter">Content in 1<button>Delete</button></div>
<div id="en_2" class="counter">Another Content<button>Delete</button></div>
<div id="en_3" class="counter">Third<button>Delete</button></div>
<div id="en_4" class="counter">Four<button>Delete</button></div>
<div id="en_5" class="counter">¿?<button>Delete</button></div>
<div id="en_6" class="counter">Jeje<button>Delete</button></div>
<div id="en_7" class="counter">On sale<button>Delete</button></div>
```

js

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
    let div = $(this).closest('div')
    let idDiv = $(div).attr('id')
    let numberDeleted = idDiv.split('_')[1]
    div.remove()

    let divs = $('.counter')

    $.each(divs, function(i, v){
        let id = $(v).attr('id')
      let number = id.split('_')[1]
      if (number > numberDeleted ) {
        $(v).attr('id', `en_${number - 1}`)
        console.log(number)
      }
    })
  })
})
```